# is it true that $T(S(v))=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $S(T(v))=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$T, S$ are linear transformations between vector spaces, $v$ is a vector.

I tried to prove it:
$$S(v)\in KerT \implies Span(S(v)) \subseteq KerT$$
but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: It''s important to state the problem correctly! Here it could be there are more conditions given on $T$ and $S$.  Or it could be the problem is "prove or give counterexample", and you're translating that to "prove" for no good reason...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I know. but this wasn't a "problem", it was one of the steps of a proof and also the only one I didn't understand, and I thought writing the full proof just for one step would have been a waste of time. but if it's false generally, there must be something else I'm missing...

Comment: Whatever. Whether you want to call it a "problem" or not, the wording of your question assumes that the statement is true. You (evidently)  had no good reason for this assumption, so it shouldn't be there - the question would be much better if it asked whether the statement was true.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I assumed it was true because my professor used it to prove something else, I just didn't know I was missing something else about the context when I wrote the question. but you're right, I'll edit it.

Comment: May I see part of lecture note where professor used above proposition for something?

Comment: @Pseudocoder proof that given an endomorphism T on a finite dimensional vector space V, generalized eigenspaces E(d) (where d is an eigenvalue) are T-invariant.

proof: if vector v belongs to E(d), then there exists a positive integer k such that ((T-d Id)^k)(v)=0. 
applying T on both sides: 
T(((T-d Id)^k)(v))=0 
iff (here is the proposition) 
((T-d Id)^k)(T(v))=0. 
therefore T(v) belongs to E(d).

Comment: Could you check it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally not true, consider the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $AB e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1  \\
0\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0  \\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

But $BA e_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1  \\
0\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0  \\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}$.

---

### Addendum

(Continuing from comments)

That is because $T$ and $(T-Id)^k$ commute.

Precisely, $\,T(T-Id)^k = (T-Id)^k  T\,\,$ gives your proposition. (Note that this is **really** a special case.)

Why commute?

$$
[T(T-Id)^k] \,\,v= T ((T-Id)^k v) \overset{\mathrm{(*)}}{=} T \,\sum_{m=0}^{k} {k \choose m} \,\,(-d)^{k-m} \,\,(T^m\,v)=\sum_{m=0}^{k} {k \choose m} \,\,(-d)^{k-m} \,\,(T^{m+1}\,v) \\=\sum_{m=0}^{k} {k \choose m} \,\,(-d)^{k-m} \,\,(T^{m}\,(Tv)) \overset{\mathrm{(*)}}{=} (T-Id)^k \,\,Tv = [(T-Id)^kT]\,\,v.
$$

---

I will prove (*): $(T + aI)^k (v) = \sum_{m=0}^{k} {k \choose m} \,\,a^{k-m}\, (T^m\, v)$ by induction with $k$.

Note that $T^0 \equiv I$ and case of $k=1$ is clear.
$$
(T + aI)^k (v) = (T + aI)^{k-1} (Tv + av) = \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} {k-1 \choose m} \,\,a^{k-1-m}\, T^m(Tv + av)
$$
Where last equality comes from Induction Hypothesis(for $k-1$).

Then
$$
= \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} {k-1 \choose m} \,\,a^{k-1-m}\, T^{m+1} v + \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} {k-1 \choose m} \,\,a^{k-m}\, T^{m} v\\=\sum_{m=1}^{k} {k-1 \choose m-1} \,\,a^{k-m}\, T^{m} v + \sum_{m=0}^{k-1} {k-1 \choose m} \,\,a^{k-m}\, T^{m} v
\\ =\sum_{m=0}^{k} {k \choose m} \,\,a^{k-m}\, T^{m} v.$$

Proof completed by induction.

---

Also note that for polynomial $f$ and $g$,
$$
f(T)g(T) = (fg)(T) = (gf)(T) = g(T)f(T)
$$
You can prove this also easily.

Comment: I'm just not familiar with this kind of proves at all so I didn't notice newton's binomial at first. it's clear now, thank you

Comment: Sure :)ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ